# Set value of div to shown/hidden after POST based on value of drop down list

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm try to set the value of a div to be hidden or not based on the value of a drop down list, and I can't get it working after a post, when the form is redisplyed with validation errors.  I'm using ASP.NET MVC>

I have a drop down list called ddlBookType which can be blank, or have the value "A" or "B"

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
x => x.Book.Type,
Model.Types, "", new { @style = "width:50%", @id = "ddlBookType" })<br />
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ICLA.Type)
```

I have a div called BookDetails which I only want to show if the above drop down list is set to B:

```
<div id="BookDetails">
    // Only show if ddlBookType is "B"
</div>
```

I have a small function which toggles the visibility of the above DIV based on the value of ddlBookType:

```
$("#ddlBookType").change(function () {
    $('#BookDetails').toggle(this.value == 'B');
});
```

This works well, but if my form is posted, then I need to show/hide the BookDetails div based on the value of ddlBookType.  I've tried:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($("#ddlBookType").value == 'B') {
        $('#BookDetails').show()
    }
    else {
        $('#BookDetails').hide()

    }

})
```

But this seems to always evaluate to false.  So when my user goes to the form for the first time the div is hidden (good), but when the form is posted and redisplayed with validation errors, the div is also hidden, irrespective of the value of ddlBookType.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `value` property with `javascript` object not with jQuery object. As `$("#ddlBookType")` gives you jQuery object which can be converted to javascript `DOM` object by using indexer. Alternatively you can use val() with jQuery object instead of using value.

*Change*

```
if ($("#ddlBookType").value == 'B')
```

*To*

```
if ($("#ddlBookType")[0].value == 'B')
```

Or

```
if ($("#ddlBookType").val() == 'B')
```